# Searching entire storage of phone and SD Card for Music Player

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Back when I started to make this **music player**, just searching in the `SD Card` would work and show the music and the player would work properly. A couple weeks ago, I bought a new phone and decided to install the app onto it, but when I loaded the app, it couldn't find any music, so I need a way to change the current code so that it will search every folder of the phone, and the `micro SD Card` , for any file which ends in ".mp3".

**Main Activity.java**

```
class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    return (name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnCompletionListener {
private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
private static final String PHONE_STORAGE = new String(Environment.getRootDirectory().getPath() + "/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
private View play;
private View pause;
private View stop;
private View next;
private View prev;
private View replay;
private View shuffle;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
public static int SONG_NUMBER = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    updatePlaylist();
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    prev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    replay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    shuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    next.setEnabled(false);
    prev.setEnabled(false);
    replay.setEnabled(false);
    shuffle.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    try {
        SONG_NUMBER = position;
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + PHONE_STORAGE + songs.get(position));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        play.setEnabled(false);
        pause.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        next.setEnabled(true);
        prev.setEnabled(true);
        replay.setEnabled(true);
        shuffle.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void updatePlaylist() {
    File home = new File(SD_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.song_item, songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);
    }
    File secondDirectory = new File(PHONE_STORAGE);
    if (secondDirectory.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
            songs.add(file.getName());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.song_item, songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);
    }
}

public void play(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing song",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp.start();
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    next.setEnabled(true);
    prev.setEnabled(true);
    replay.setEnabled(true);
    shuffle.setEnabled(true);
}

public void pause(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pausing song",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp.pause();
    play.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
    next.setEnabled(true);
    prev.setEnabled(true);
    replay.setEnabled(false);
    shuffle.setEnabled(false);
}

public void stop(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopping song",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp.stop();
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    next.setEnabled(false);
    prev.setEnabled(false);
    replay.setEnabled(false);
    shuffle.setEnabled(false);
    isRepeat = false;
    isShuffle = false;
}

public void next(View view) {
    isRepeat = false;
    try {
        if (isShuffle) {
            mp.reset();
            Random rand = new Random();
            SONG_NUMBER = rand.nextInt((songs.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + PHONE_STORAGE + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }
        else {
        if (SONG_NUMBER < songs.size() - 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Next song",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + PHONE_STORAGE + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SONG_NUMBER = -1;
        }
        mp.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void prev(View view) {
    isRepeat = false;
    isShuffle = false;
    try {
        if (SONG_NUMBER == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Cannot play previous song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            prev.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Previous song",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + PHONE_STORAGE + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            SONG_NUMBER -= 2;
        }
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.prevButton), e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void replay(View view) {

    if (isRepeat) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Replaying All Songs",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isRepeat = false;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Replaying Current Song",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isRepeat = true;
        isShuffle = false;
    }

}

public void shuffle(View view) {
    if (isShuffle) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Songs Normally",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isShuffle = false;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffling Songs",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isShuffle = true;
        isRepeat = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp1) {
    try {
        if (isRepeat) {
            mp.start();
        } else if (isShuffle) {
            mp.reset();
            Random rand = new Random();
            SONG_NUMBER = rand.nextInt((songs.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } else {
            mp.reset();
            SONG_NUMBER += 1;
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(SONG_NUMBER));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }
        play.setEnabled(false);
        pause.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        next.setEnabled(true);
        prev.setEnabled(true);
        replay.setEnabled(true);
        shuffle.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post so much irrelevant code. Moreover we are not interested in all your buttons. Post only the relevant code where you try to list the mp3 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to search individual files in storages. MediaStore does it for you.Every audio file will be listed here

**Updated**

```
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    };

            Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    null,
                    null);

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            //do something with the path
            File f=new File(cursor.getString(0));
            System.out.println(cursor.getString(0));
            }
```

Comment: I have no idea on what mediastore is, but all i would like is to change the strings which search for the files so that it searches everywhere. By the look of the code you have above, it gives the artist, album and track and then i have to somehow implement it into the code so that it sets that as the data source. This app is a very simple music player which just has a list of songs and buttons to play, pause and other random things. there is no artist or album and so no real need of the cursor_cols.

Comment: You just want file paths?Thats possible too by using MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA. See my updated answer

Comment: Ok, so how would I implement that so that it sets the data source of the media player as the code you have posted? This music player started off as a simple tutorial that I followed and grew it from there so I don't really know that much of Android programming in java yet.

Comment: i think the updated code i added in the answer in understandable enough.Isn't it?